# keyword="value" regular expression

Tags: regex

My regular expression

```
(?<Keyword>\w+)\s*=\s*\"(?<Value>\w+)\"
```

is not correct to match all my keyword, value pair in my

```
oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_nonce="K7WmP9YrR2oCYC3", oauth_timestamp="1413801976", oauth_consumer_key="test", oauth_signature="8ad2fZh23q%2FWfK6RykqcvhlLxH4%3D"
```

Because I use \w It only match with 3 groups. I need something that also match with .%- Do you know what I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negated character class `[^\"]` instead of `\w+` to match any character  but nof of `"` one or more times.

```
(?<Keyword>\w+)\s*=\s*\"(?<Value>[^\"]+)\"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dK1xR4/8)

Comment: @B413 this will also accept specail characters like `!@#` etc.are these valid?

Comment: @vks i explained my regex . I think after seeing the explanation , op accepted this.

Comment: Yeah that's what i wanna make sure :) coz that was not there is OP's requirement. `I need something that also match with .%-`

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<Keyword>\w+)\s*=\s*\"(?<Value>[\w.%-]+)\"
```

Try this.This will give all the groups.

Changed `\w` to `[\w.%-]` to include `.` , `%`, and `-`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dK1xR4/7